# Change Values of coordinates of map

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, input

I have the following code,

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
var map;

$(document).ready(function() {
    initialize();

    $("#menu").on("click", ".panTo", function() {
        var laLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(4.6747035,-74.0575514); /My question
        map.panTo(laLatLng);
            var marker = new google.maps.Circle({
            strokeColor: "#8ada55",
            fillColor: "#bcff8f",
            strokeOpacity: 0.8,
            strokeWeight: 2,
            fillOpacity: 0.5,
            map: map,
            center: laLatLng,
            radius:300
            }); 
    });
});

function initialize() {
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 15,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(4.5980556,-74.0758333),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), myOptions);;
}
</script>

<div id="map_canvas" style="width: 650px; height:400px"></div>
<div id="menu">
    <label>Location 1</label>
    <input type="button" class="panTo" value="4.6747035,-74.0575514" />
    <br /><br />
</div>
```

My question is how to set in the Javascript Code, the value from the input's Value.?

Exactly in this line: LatLng(4.6747035,-74.0575514);

Because I will have plenty address, with buttoms, so when someone click on the buttom that LatLng must be update.

Comment: Some basic Javascript + DOM tutorial would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the information given it appears that you're trying to set the value of the latlng depending on what is passed into the anonymous function. correct me if I'm wrong.

This is the documentation for Jquery .on and it shows how to pass data through your anonymous function.
http://api.jquery.com/on/

> .on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler(eventObject) )
>
> Data to be passed to the handler in event.data when an event is triggered.

so, your lat and lng would be passed in to through the event.data object to your function where you can use them in your latlng object as you please.

Hope that was what you were asking

Answer (score 0):

Probably need to include references to some Google includes but there are a couple of things here:

1. When using "new" in JavaScript, there is a reference to (some) object definition.
   This is not clear in this question.
   new google.maps.LatLng
2. Generally, the "google.maps" object appears to have a property "LatLng".
   Using "onclick" function on a web-control for example, call JavaScript that modifies this property as: google.maps.LatLng = (x,y);

However, the caveat here is that we don't know what this object is and if it is a method/property. If it is some kind of function or a constructor, then review the documentation for the Google library "maps" object definition to see how to set the "LatLng" property (might be through method-call, in constructor as defined, etc).

Based on this, another option is to set a global variable and create a new object as:

var myMap = new google.maps.LatLng(x,y);
where: x and y are inputs to the JavaScript function.